# DATEDIFF not working in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am not able to use DATEDIFF and CURRENT_TIME in symfony2 repository. Same problem is there while I am using year function..why this is happening?

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
                            ->createQuery("SELECT u FROM AcmeAdminBundle:AppUsers u  WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIME(), u.dob) BETWEEN :fromage AND :toage and u.country = :countries ORDER BY u.id DESC")
                            ->setParameter('fromage', $fromage)
                            ->setParameter('toage', $toage)
                            ->setParameter('countries', $countrystr);
```

this query working properly if I did not use the above functions

Comment: And if you save the result into a variable, what `var_dump()` would say?

Comment: Seems it is not Symfony (or Doctrine) problem. May be problem is in MySql. Check your MySql version. DATEDIFF() function started on the v4.1.1

Comment: How exactly are you unable to use it? Is there an exception thrown? Or does the returned result somehow differ from what you're expecting? Please specify this, otherwise the question is hard to answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Base on the link ([DQL Functions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions)) the `DATEDIFF` is defined and is valid in Doctrine just you need to change it from `DATEDIFF(expr1, expr2)` to `DATE_DIFF(expr1, expr2)`.
Furthermore, if your field is a datetime field it's better to use `CURRENT_DATE()` instead of `NOW()` or `CURRENT_TIME()`

Comment: +1 Thanks to correcting me, I was sure that it was not supported yet by default :-)